# How to get javascript to throw error on bad date input?

Tags: javascript, date

```js
console.log(new Date("2000-02-31"));
```

The above will work. It will it convert to `2000-03-02T00:00:00.000Z`.

How do I override this behavior and get it to throw an error on garbage input?

Comment: Febrarury only has 29 days at most

Comment: Any implementation that parses "2000-02-31" as a valid date is not compliant with [ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse), it must return an invalid Date: "*Strings that are unrecognizable or contain out-of-bounds format element values shall cause Date.parse to return NaN*".

Comment: There are a lot of date libraries that are useful for this sort of thing.  Check out Moment.js.  They're quite chonky though.

Comment: Oh, to answer "*How do I override this behavior and get it to throw an error on garbage input?*" you can't, you can only parse it separately and throw an error yourself.